# Serializer Test serializer.is_valid() = False

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models, Parent an Child(fk Parent) and 2 serializers:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    children = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = (
            'username',
            ...
            'url',
            'children',
        )

    def get_children(self, obj):
        queryset = Child.objects.filter(parent=obj)
        children = ChildSerializer(queryset, many=True, context=self.context).data
        return children


class ChildSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = [
            'parent',
            ...
            'url',
        ]
```

My TestCase:

```
class TestSerializers(TestCase):
    def test_child_serializer(self):
        parent_data = {
            'username': 'JohnSnow',
            ...
        }
        parent = Parent.objects.create_user(**user_data)
        parent.set_password('jon12345')
        child_data = {
            'parent': {
                 'username': "JohnSnow",
                 ...
            },
            # 'parent': user,
            ...
        }

        serializer = ChildSerializer(data=sample_ig_user_data)
    if not serializer.is_valid():
        print(serializer.errors)
```

My error: `{'parent': ['Incorrect type. Expected URL string, received dict.']}`

First, I tried to pass the parent both as a dictionary, and as a created object.
There is a nuance, in the child serializer the parent is transferred simply as a hyperlink (in the browser in api so it is displayed)
By the way how to transfer the serializer of the parent to the child serializer, if I already imported the child in the parent, the circular import is because?

And the second question, about the error, I understand that I either transfer the data to the dictionary incorrectly or incorrectly process it after?
Please help. universal Thank you!

Comment: Please make sure you paste relevant code sample. This one doesn't tell use what `sample_ig_user_data` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Incorrect type. Expected URL string, received dict.` -> you need to pass the parent's primary key:

```
child_data = {
    ...
    'parent': parent.pk,
    ...
}
```